# What is the EASA equivalent of the FAA's 91.517?

Tags: faa-regulations, safety, commercial-aviation, easa-regulations

What is the EASA equivalent of the US [91.517](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&SID=03efb7c1b34301bf39ff6d98084cdd45&rgn=div8&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.3.10.6.7.9&idno=14) regulations (on passenger information)?

Answer (score 1):

The EASA regulation regarding passenger briefings begins at **AMC1 CAT.OP.MPA.170 Passenger briefing.**

Here is a link to the document where the above specific reference can be read:
[click here](http://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/Consolidated%20unofficial%20AMC-GM_Annex%20IV%20Part-CAT%20March%202018.pdf)